# Selenium edge driver cannot go to extension page

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge-extension, selenium-edgedriver

I'm using Selenium 4 to do some automation and currently we just use it on chrome driver. I'm adding support for edge and got to that problem. (Using C#)

On chrome I can go to a extension settings page by doing:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("chrome-extension://<extensionId>/html/settings.html");
```

With that I can go to the settings page of my extension on chrome. However when I try the same code on edge (with the correct edge extension path) it doesn't work but when I copy and paste it directly to the browser and press enter it goes fine. Do anyone have any input?

```
edgeDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("extension://<extensionId>/html/settings.html");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you should replace `extension` with `chrome-extension` in your URL

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
edgeDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("chrome-extension://<extensionId>/html/settings.html");
```